# eclipse setting build path encountered error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, buildpath

i have two different app projects:- **1st: Wallpaper App** and **2nd: Crop Wallpaper**.

and i want to install both app project with one installation? instead of installing then individually.

i tried this below:

In eclipse right click on

> OneProject>Properties>java Build Path>

In right window click

> Project>Add>Crop Wallpaper Project>OK>OK

after click OK button got this error: see error screenshot : http://s17.postimg.org/dz38um6lr/Untitled.png

```
Could not write file: C:\Users\VICKY\workspace\111FreeWallpapersApp\.classpath.
C:\Users\VICKY\workspace\111FreeWallpapersApp\.classpath (Access is denied)
```

Comment: Sounds like something else may have that particular file open at the time you are accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1st: Go To Control Panel > Folder Option > In Folder Option Window, Select View Tab > Under  Hidden Files And Folders > Select Show Hidden Files, Folders And Drives > Apply > OK

Step 2: Go To Your Workspace > Open Project Folder > Right Click `.classpath` > Select Properties > Uncheck Read Only And Hidden Attributes.

Now You Are Able To Write To `.classpath`